# GTM fires tags perfectly but Google Analytics does not reflect any Real Time/ regular click events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I am trying to track click events in my website using GTM and Google Analytics. GTM fires tags fine but GA does not show any events in real time or after 24 hours in Behavior -> Events.

I have installed Google Tag Manager as mentioned in several websites and created variable, triggers, tags as needed.

On my website, I can see that GTM fires the tags to send the information to GA but GA doesn't show any real time click events or events for that matter. Even after 24 hours, I don't see any events being tracked under Behaviour -> Events.

Note: My website is being tracked by both Google Analytics and GTM. I have not created pageviews tracking through GTM to avoid data being sent to GA twice.

I have done everything as mentioned, Created Trigger which triggers only when a click URL has certain text buttonNext. Created a Tag by providing Category, Action, Label, value and Google tracking id (tried both ways by using a GA tracking constant and direct value). In the website, when a the button with Click URL contains buttonNext is clicked, I can see the tag being fired in the GTM preview/debugger. Also, Google Tag assistant confirms that event is being sent to the provided GA Tracking id. I have made sure the tracking id provided is mapped to my website. After all this, Google Analytics is not tracking the click events. I waited for 24 hours still no data logged in the events and I modified the non interaction hit to true and false to see if that matters. Nothing did the trick.

I expect GA to track events as GTM fires tags in preview mode and GA Tag Assistant confirms the event is triggerred but GA does not track any events.

Comment: Do you have the console output of the GA Debug as well?

Comment: Try to check filters in GA view settings.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - There are no filters in my GA, Checked both in view filters and overall accounts filters. Please let me know if you want me to check anything else.

Comment: What happens if you run ga('myTracker.send', 'event', 'Click', 'Next, 'Next',1); within the console? so bypassing GTM completely. Does it then show up?

Comment: @Marcel Dumount, Running below command in console did show a spike in the events in the real time ga('send','event','Click','Next','Next', 1);
Please let me know how do I deploy this command through GTM without hard coding this send command on every button click in my website.

Comment: @Marcel Dumont, I can see that with every tag fire, my website is trying to run GA Command something like below and it's event is not shown in real time: 
ga("gtm5.send", {hitType: "event", eventCategory: "Click", eventAction: "Next", eventLabel: "Next", eventValue: 1});
but when modified this command by removing gmt5 object manually, it is showing up the real time events: 
ga("send", {hitType: "event", eventCategory: "Click", eventAction: "Next", eventLabel: "Next", eventValue: 1});
I understand, GTM creates object with every click/action and uses it but how do I remove this object here?

Comment: Have a look at the Google Tag Manager Form Tracking Flow to see in which category you fall in. 
https://www.analyticsmania.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Google-Tag-Manager-Form-Tracking-Flow-1.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Marce Dumont. 
I was able to figure out the issue - My Google Tag manager is creating new object like gmt1, gmt2 with every new click which is being used to call GA command. I had to update the GA tracking id Variable configuration - In advanced configuration, Selected "Set Tracker Name" and left it blank - This removed the object name in GA command. Now I can see the events in real time and in Behavior -> events. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you to decide on either implementing all Google Analytics tracking through GTM OR implementing all tracking natively. This will lead to a cleaner "tracking environment". There are different pros and cons that you should take into considerations when deciding on which way you want to go.

If it's a "minor website" where you have access to the source code, page speed is important and you will not do a lot of updates on the tracking I would recommend you to implement the tracking natively. Otherwise, implement all Google Analytics tracking using GTM.

However, regarding your issue, it's hard to say what is causing the issue since you didn't attach any code, screenshots, etc. My recommendation is that you open dev tools in your browser -> go to the network tab -> the filter on "collect". There you will be able to see all HTTP request that is sent to Google Analytics. If you don't see any network call being sent once triggering your event = something is wrong. You can also inspect the network call by clicking on it and under "Headers" see what values that are sent to Google Analytics.